# WPF Webbrowser Getelementby ID return incorrect Element

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I build a simple app that find and return element in VS 2015 Webbrowser with GetelementbyID function. Everything's ok, when I auto login the website and get/set data of element in some pages with GetelementbyID function. 
However, in some pages, the GetelementbyID function can not return correct Element or it can not find element by ID. 
Here's the code:

```
private void IDSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        htmldoc = Window.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;            
        IHTMLElement newElement = htmldoc.getElementById(Elementag.Text);
        if (newElement != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can access element: " + htmldoc.getElementById(Elementag.Text).title );
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not get element");
        }
    }
```

HTML: With this element, getelementbyID can not find the Element:

```html
<input title="Date Start" class="fld text" id="mx1180" lang="en-us" style=";width:127.5px;" type="text" value="" ctype="textbox" work="1" li="mx1181" fldinfo='{"length":"10","inttype":"4","lookup":"datelookup","eventpriority":1}' ae="setvalue" async="1" dojovalue="1469678688446" lng="en" datepackage="" constraints="{datePattern:'dd/MM/yyyy', timePattern:'hh:mm a',locale:'en-us',visibleRange: 'T03:30:00'}" popuptype="ibm.tivoli.mbs.dijit.DateTimeCalendar" df="1" originalvalue="" prekeyvalue="" stoptcclick="true">
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is elementtag? Maybe your webpage does not have an element with the given id?